# Can’t require global npm module

Tags: javascript, npm

I have the following problem. I install uuid with `npm install -g uuid`.
When I try to run the following code:

```
var uuid = require("uuid");
console.log(uuid.v1());
```

an exception is thrown:

```
module.js:339
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'uuid'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (d:\CodingProjects\HTML\TestJavascript.js:16:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
```

If I install the module locally with `npm install uuid` it works fine.
But why is that? What should I do, to make my global packages working?
I tried to download it from `Language & Frameworks -> Javascript -> Libraries`, but I still get an exception if I don't install it locally for my project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is in how `npm` installs packages.

When you run `npm install -g <package>`, you tell `npm` to install the `<package>` globally. This works when you want to use the package as a command line tool, like, for example, [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/):

```
$ npm install -g gulp
$ cd path/to/project
$ gulp
```

However, this does not work when you want to depend on a package.

To depend on a package, you should install it locally, i. e. in the project directory. This is one of the `npm`’s key benefits: local installation makes managing dependencies and upgrading them much easier for you. The `npm install` command without `-g` flag is dedicated exactly for that. When you run

```
$ npm install uuid
```

in, say, `foo` directory, a `foo/node_modules` directory is created, and `uuid` module is installed there. After that, you could create a `.js` file in the `foo` directory (or any its subdirectory), require the `uuid` module from it, and everything will work.

---

As to WebStorm: downloading a library from `Language & Frameworks → Javascript → Libraries` does not actually download an `npm` package, it just downloads and installs the library type definitions. Type definitions help WebStorm build better autocompletion when you use a library in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helps me to understand how this things work.

Comment: @DPM: I’m glad it’s helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use your global packages, all you need to do is create a link between your global package from within your local directory.
This is also known as creating a symbolic link (symlink).

So, running the "npm link uui" in your local directory would allow you to use the global package wihout having to download it into your local directory.
If you analyze the local directory you'll notice that a (linked) folder has been created, meaning it is merely a pointer to the global package.

So, in short, if you want to use global packages, then "npm link" is the way to do it.