# NPM: Cannot find module 'uuid'

Tags: npm

I have this message when i try to use npm:

```
> $ npm
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot found module 'uuid'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.ks:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/metrics.js:10:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

I tried to uninstall reinstall with brew but without success.

Answer (score 23):

You might have seen the error because of this

```
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');
```

try to replace it with this one

```
const { v1: uuidv1 } = require('uuid');
```

Comment: is this then simply called like this: `uuidv1()` ?

Answer (score 20):

You can try (ECMAScript Module syntax)

```
import { v1 as uuidv1 } from 'uuid';
console.log(uuidv1()); //=> f68f7b70-9606-11ea-9ccc-fbd3ee221c8f
```

With v4

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
uuidv4(); // ⇨ '9b1deb4d-3b7d-4bad-9bdd-2b0d7b3dcb6d'
```

for more: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Answer (score 12):

do

```
 npm install uuid
```

And then in your app.js file do

```
var uuid = require('uuid');
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');

console.log(uuid.v1());
```

Answer (score 7):

There's an error in the most recently versions of 'uuid'. Try to install:

```
npm install uuid@3.3.3
```

or with yarn

```
yarn add uuid@3.3.3
```

I've got the answer from [this tutorial](https://medium.com/xp-inc/criando-uma-api-restful-com-nodejs-e-express-m%C3%A9todo-post-f0c4cc1a5f06)

Comment: I can confirm that on my AWS EC2 server I could run 3.4.0 successfully but the latest version 8.x resulted in an error

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1')
```

Use this

```
const uuidv1 = require('uuid');

   console.log(uuidv1.v1())
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it improves on the other answers this question has, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when you import as `const uuid= require('uuid/dist/v4');`

```
code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
```

So the new import is

```js
   import const {v4:uuid4} =require('uuid');
```

which solves the issue.
You can refer this link for more information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid.

Answer (score 1):

Run this terminal command:

```sh
npm install uuid
```

This will output something like this:

```sh
uuid@8.2.0
added 454 packages from 181 contributors, removed 144 packages, updated 1399 packages and audited 1862 packages in 712.444s
```

next step import this to your `js` file

```js
import { v8 as uuidv8 } from 'uuid';
```

Answer (score 0):

When we import:

```
const uuid = require("uuid");
```

When we call it we need also specify the version:

```
uuid.v4();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `/v1` from the path and try

```
const uuid = require('uuid');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried following changes and it works for me.

```
const uuidV1 = require('uuid').v1;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. ```
   npm install uuid --save
   ```
2. ```
   import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
   ```
3. *Assign which Variable to you want. this is hold on Unique id* -

   ```
    uuidv4();
   ```
4. *After that you again Install Packages* -

   ```
   npm install
   ```
5. *This is method Working 100% in Angular project*.

You will Try...!

Answer (score 0):

Add this in `tsConfig.json` if you are using Angular version 14:

```
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "types":["uuid"],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sometimes**, you just have to save the types which are by default not saved by npm

```
npm i --save-dev @types/module-name
```

Then you can easily import the module however you wish. I faced the same problem in uuid module.It was resolved by this.

Answer (score -1):

Just do:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

then:

```
npm prune
```

Comment: So Reason from how you install npm. Please refer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707522/can-t-require-global-npm-module

Answer (score -1):

answer is do try this -update your `package.json  "uuid": "^3.3.2"`
and `npm install`
its