# npm cannot run in Debian: Error: Cannot find module 'node-uuid'

Tags: node.js

Not really good with this JavaScript world. Trying to install npm and I think it's broken. I'm using Debian and ran:
`apt install npm`.
Everything went fine but when I run `npm` it throws up this error

```
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node-uuid'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:29:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
```

Nothing works, i can't install the `node-uuid` either.

Comment: all you need to do is install `Node.JS`, npm comes bundled with that. not do not install node from the default ubuntu repositories

Comment: I have `nodejs` installed but it doesn't come with npm

Comment: what does `node -v` give you

Comment: node -v: `v8.9.3`

Comment: what about `npm -v`

Comment: That's the problem, I can't get that. I get the error above anytime i run `npm`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865189/error-cannot-find-module-uuid

Comment: Yes, but it didn't solve my issue. `npm` was broken completely

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this, I think there's a problem with the package on Debian repo.
I followed the instruction on Node website

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

I have npm installed now :)